# Incorrect type passed into template. Based on the x:DataType global::SMARTWms.Model.Login was expected

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

By followed the sample from here https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlListView/cs/Samples/MasterDetailSelection, i created a master detail page named SecuritySettingsPage.

The master detail page works fine until I put it under Pivot in another page as shown below:

```
<PivotItem Header="Security">
<view:SecuritySettingsPage />
</PivotItem>
```

The above error happened whenever i browse to that particular pivot when running the program. The error would go away and pivot display data correctly if i click the "Continue" button from the Visual Studio.

I have no idea on how to resolve it. Could anyone enlighten me please?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the above by passing a null DataContext.

```
<PivotItem Header="Security">
<view:SecuritySettingsPage DataContext="{x:Null}"/>
</PivotItem>
```